HPA unable to read metrics from Google Managed Prometheus
We were trying to use metrics exported from our app to Google Manager Prometheus. Even though we are able to view the metrics in Google Monitoring, the HPA is not able to read the values and we are getting an error: "HPA cannot read metric value"
Attaching screenshots of kubectl describe hpa -n aries and Google Monitoring


Tried configuring the HPA using the GCP console but still got the save error
Edit 1
GKE Version: 1.27.14-gke.1059002
As of now I am able to get CPU resource based HPA to work.
This is the YAML file I am using to manage the HPA settings
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: aries-celery-hpa
  namespace: aries
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: aries-celery
  minReplicas: {{ .Values.spec_celery.hpa.min_replicas }}
  maxReplicas: {{ .Values.spec_celery.hpa.max_replicas }}
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: {{ .Values.spec_celery.hpa.metrics.cpu.averageUtilization}}

  - type: External
    external:
      metric:
        name: prometheus.googleapis.com|aries_backlog_pressure|gauge
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 2

metrics.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
  name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.spec.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: "low-cpu"
        operator: "Equal"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
        value: "true"

      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: "low-cpu"
                operator: "In"
                values:
                - "true"
      containers:
        - image: {{ .Values.image.name }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["python3", "metrics.py"]
          name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
          ports:
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: aries-config
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: "/app/.env"
              subPath: .env
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: {{ .Values.spec.resources.limits.cpu }}
              memory: {{ .Values.spec.resources.limits.memory }}

            requests:
              cpu: {{ .Values.spec.resources.requests.cpu }}
              memory: {{ .Values.spec.resources.requests.memory }}

      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      volumes:
        - name: aries-config
          configMap:
            name: aries-config
            items:
              - key: .env
                path: .env
            defaultMode: 420


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
  namespace: aries
spec:
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: metrics
  type: LoadBalancer

---

apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
kind: PodMonitoring
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.app_name }}-metric-exporter
  endpoints:
  - port: metrics
    interval: 30s


You don't include much detail. Have you read this

Could you please check and update here if you are getting any other metrics of HPA, and add which version of GKE you are using and add yaml files of deployment which can help to reproduce the issue.

@SaiChandraGadde I have included the YAML file which I am using for the HPA along with the definition of the pod which is exporting the prometheus metrics to google cloud monitoring.

Have you checked this thread, here they have added metric in hpa

@SaiChandraGadde I went through the thread and tried the fixes. They still were not of any help. However I came across the issue where the custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter is not able to read the prometheus metrics.
